# MVC Entity Framework Partial Class access DB for property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework mapped to my database. I have a Basket model which can have many BasketItem models, and I have Promotions and Coupons models.
This is for eCommerce checkout functionality and I just don't understand how this will work, here goes:

Because my BasketItems have a foreign key relationship to the Basket if I want to sum up the Subtotal for my basket items in a partial class, I can do this:

```
        public decimal Subtotal {
        get {
            return this.BasketItems.Sum(pb => pb.Subtotal);
            }
        }
```

This is helpful because I can use this inside a view, there's no mucking around with passing a DB context through and it's DRY, etc. etc.

Now I want to apply promotions or coupons to my Subtotal ideally I want it to look like this:

```
        public decimal DiscountedSubtotal {
        get { 
            decimal promotions_discount = 0;
            decimal coupons_discount = 0;
            return Subtotal - promotions_discount - coupons_discount;
            }
        }
```

But there is no access to Promotions or Coupons without either creating some crazy and unnecessary relationships in my database or some light hacking to get this functionality to work. I don't know what I should do to overcome this problem.

**Solution 1:**

```
        public decimal DiscountedSubtotal(DatabaseEntities db) {
        decimal promotions_discount = from p in db.Promotions
                                  select p.Amount;
        decimal coupons_discount = from c in db.Coupons
                               select c.Amount;
        return Subtotal - promotions_discount - coupons_discount;
        }
```

I don't want to use this in my View pages, plus I have to send through my context every time I want to use it.

**Solution 2: (untested)**

```
    public List<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
    public List<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }

    public Basket()
        : base() {
            DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
            Promotions = db.Promotions.ToList();
            Coupons = db.Coupons.ToList();
    }
```

A bit of light hacking could provide me with references to promotions and coupons but i've had problems with creating new contexts before and I don't know if there is a better way to get me to the DiscountedSubtotal property I would ideally like.

So to sum up my question, I would like to know the best way to get a DiscountedSubtotal property.

Many thanks and apologies for such a long read :)

Comment: Can you provide the code for Promotions and Coupons, as well as your view and model?  Also, what do you mean that you've had problems with creating new contexts?

Comment: Promotions and Coupons are just your plain old entity framework mapped objects. If I create a new instance of my context inside of an object that has a reference to the context it causes a runtime error stating both cannot be used at the same time or something.

Comment: It sounds like your connection string is missing `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

Comment: oo I'll have to give that a go, thanks :) Doesn't sound like it'll be too friendly in shared hosting environment though :/

Comment: Not sure what a shared hosting environment has to do with anything..

Comment: I already have memory issues using Entity Framework on most shared hosting environments, allowing multiple result sets would affect that further perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're not really using a coherent architecture.

In most cases, you should have a business layer to handle this kind of logic.  Then that business layer would have functions like `CalculateDiscountForProduct()` or `CalculateNetPrice()` that would go out to the database and retrieve the data you need to complete the business rule.

The business class would talk to a data layer that returns data objects.  Your view only needs it's view model, which you populate from the business objects returned by your businesss layer.

A typical method might be:

```
public ActionResult Cart() {
    var model = _cartService.GetCurrentCart(userid);
    return View(model);
}
```

So when you apply a discount or coupon, you would call a method like `_cartService.ApplyDiscount(model.DiscountCode);` then return the new model back to the view.

You might do well to study the Mvc Music Store sample project, as it includes cart functionality and promo codes.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: I see, I keep bumping into this problem. I need to separate my View models from my Data models. Would you say I still need a business layer/wrapper between them?

Comment: Also, are you saying that MVC and 3-tier fit well together and are not opposing methodologies? thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: @Smithy - I know all the examples show data access in your controller, but that's just not a correct way to go about it long term.  Yes, MVC and 3-tier fit well together and are complementary.  MVC is a UI layer (yes, even the model) so it fits in the UI tier.  You may find this article useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En